# Does "second death" in Revelation 20:13-14 implicitly indicate "second Hades"?

Tags: revelation

In Revelation 20:13-14;

> 13. And the sea gave up the dead that were in it; and death and Hades gave up the dead that were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works.
> 14. And death and Hades were cast into the lake of fire. This is the second death, {cf15i even} the lake of fire. ASV.

Does "second death" allude to, hint or implicitly indicate that there is a "second Hades"?

What I understood from the text is that: second death is death of death, i.e: death of the first death. Thus, second Hades should be Hades of Hades, i.e: Hades of the first Hades.

And Hades is some kind of suffering or discomfort.

Hades is the word mentioned in Greek text, ASV and ESV. It is translated in KJV as "hell", in GNB as "the world of the dead".

Hades in Greek mythology is god of the underworld and it is also the underworld itself. Like Sheol in Judaism (a god and the world of that god).

God of the underworld may be interchangeable with Demon of the underworld, i.e: Demon who caused suffering for Saints, I suggest, He will suffer also, as he made Godly men suffer... that is the second death, or to be accurate, the second Hades (hell).

What I am asking about is: hermeneutically, does (second death) implicitly indicate (second Hades)?. I think this is clear from Vs 14.

Do you know some exegesises about "second Hades"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire is symbolic of destruction.  At **Re 21:4** "*death shall be  no more*." ( **ASV**) What gets put into the fire is consumed and destroyed.

> Rev 21:4 And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and **there shall be no more death**, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things are passed away (KJV)

The same would be true of Hades at **Re 20:13-14** just a few verses earlier.

Comment: death shall be no more, after the second death. The text is very clear, second death is not for Saints and believers.

Answer (score 1):

**Does “second death” in Revelation 20:13-14 implicitly indicate “second Hades”?**

Revelation 20:13-14  (NASB)

> 13 "And the sea gave up the dead which were in it, and death and Hades
>   gave up the dead which were in them; and they were judged, every one
>   of them according to their deeds. 14 Then death and Hades were thrown
>   into the lake of fire. This is the second death, the lake of fire."

The first death was originally passed on to the mankind by Adam as a result of his transgression. And since Hades and death gave up their dead, this means that (most) of the dead will be resurrected, Jesus said:

John 5:28-29  (NASB)

> 28 "Do not marvel at this; for an hour is coming, in which all who are
>   in the tombs will hear His voice, 29 and will come forth; those who
>   did the good deeds to a resurrection of life, those who committed the
>   evil deeds to a resurrection of judgment."

"And they were judged every man according to their works." after being resurrected, those who do good deeds  will be resurrected to life , but  those that persist and practice wickedness will face judgement.

The lake of fire is a symbolic place,"the second death," this is indicated by the fact that death and hades as well the devil (Mt 25:42) a spirit creature are all thrown into it, **none of which are affected by fire.**

Since  the  first death is due to inherited sin (Rom. 5:12), then the second must be quiet different,like as mentioned in the following verses:

Matthew 12:32  (NABRE)

> 32" And whoever speaks a word against the Son of Man will be forgiven;
>   but whoever speaks against the holy Spirit will not be forgiven,
>   either in this age or in the age to come."

Hebrews 10:26-27  (NET Bible)

> 26 "For if we deliberately keep on sinning after receiving the
>   knowledge of the truth, no further sacrifice for sins is left for us,
>   27 but only a certain fearful expectation of judgment and a fury of
>   fire that will consume God’s enemies."

As mentioned in the texts above   there will be  no  forgiveness for continued sinning after being resurrected and receiving the knowledge of the truth.  The lake of fire is symbolic, "the second death," is obviously  not everlasting torment, but that death will cease to exist- will be no more , for the obedient mankind. This will be achieved during the reign of Christ , Paul wrote:

1 Corinthians 15:24-26 (NET Bible)

> 24 "Then comes the end, when he hands over the kingdom to God the
>   Father, when he has brought to an end all rule and all authority and
>   power. 25 For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his
>   feet. 26 **The last enemy to be eliminated is death."** (Rev. 21:3-4)

For the saints/holy ones, those gaining the **"crown of life"** are not affected by the second death.

Revelation 2:10-11 (NASB)

> 10 "Do not fear what you are about to suffer. Behold, the devil is
>   about to cast some of you into prison, so that you will be tested, and
>   you will have tribulation for ten days. [a]Be faithful until death,
>   and I will give you the **crown of life.** 11 He who has an ear, let
>   him hear what the Spirit says to the churches. **He who overcomes will
>   not be hurt by the second death."**

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

In a sense, yes …as both the death and the Hades are together cast into the lake of fire.  They are then both called the “second death” as these two conditions are together and is the final Judgment upon the wicked.

“Hades” = “unseen” ….or not knowing.

The wicked shall not understand in the Day of Judgment as Hades is also cast into the lake of fire.

The wicked will not know the reason for their “torment” as their own tongues shall set their lives on the fire of “hell” (Gehenna) in the final Judgment upon them. Their own evil speaking shall cause themselves troubles….and they will not understand why.

> Revelation 20:14-15 KJV (14)  ***And death and hell were cast into the
>   lake of fire. This is the second death.***

We read that those who are not found written in the book of life are also cast into the lake of fire.  These are the wicked…the unbelievers.   The wicked shall not understand as Hades (the unseen…the not knowing why) is cast into the lake of fire in the final Judgment upon them.

Even though they may profess faith, they do not show it through their works as the Scriptures are opened up (the books are opened) to their hearing ears by our Lord Jesus Christ.  They will not believe in what they hear and will reveal the evil that is within their own hearts by the evil that they will speak openly towards the hearing of His voice that opens up the Scriptures.

Faith without good works is dead.  Their works shall be manifest as evil instead of good towards the opening up of the books (the Scriptures).   Good works manifests our faith. Faith is active.  It is doing what we profess.

The unbelievers shall die in their own evil speaking and their own tongues will bring themselves torment…and not know why (Hades = not knowing).

> (15)  **And whosoever was not found written in the book of life was cast
>   into the lake of fire.**

The wicked shall not understand as Hades (not knowing) is also cast into the lake of fire (the final judgment upon the wicked).  NONE of the wicked shall understand in the Day of Judgment.

> Daniel 12:10 KJV (10)  *Many shall be purified, and made white, and
>   tried; but the wicked shall do wickedly: **and none of the wicked shall
>   understand;** but the wise shall understand.*

When one is cast into the “lake of fire”, this is the judgment that is final upon those who do not believe.

It is a final judgment until one dies from this earth as Jesus told those who were rejecting Him in John 8 that they should die in their sins…their evil speaking (sins) which would give them torment as the tongue is a fire that sets oneself on fire of “hell” or Gehenna.

Gehenna is the “second death” and is the final Judgment upon those who will continue to sin (speak evil) towards the hearing of the Word of Truth.

We shall not be harmed by their speaking evil towards us by not returning evil for their evil.   The “second death” shall not harm us as we must keep the sacrifice of our Lord (the Lamb) in the presence of the divine final Judgment of God upon them for their evil speaking.

There will be no other remedy.  There will be no mercy as both death and hades are cast into the lake of fire where there will be torment “for ever and ever” (that is, no more remedy for willful sins until one dies from this earth).

The wicked shall die in their sins which will bring them torment in their lives….and not know why (Hades = unseen = not knowing). The wicked shall not understand.

> John 8:23-24 KJV (23)  *And he said unto them, Ye are from beneath; I
>   am from above: ye are of this world; I am not of this world. (24)  **I
>   said therefore unto you, that ye shall die in your sins: for if ye
>   believe not that I am he, ye shall die in your sins.***

Jesus asked them how could they then escape the judgment of “hell”…that is, Gehenna?  It is a final judgment then. It is one without mercy and cannot be escaped except for our own death from this earth.

> Matthew 23:33 KJV (33)  **Ye serpents, ye generation of vipers, how can
>   ye escape the damnation of hell?**

He called them a “generation of vipers” as they could not speak anything good (continuing to sin) towards Him.  Everything that they said was evil always towards Him.

> Matthew 12:33-37 KJV (33)  Either make the tree good, and his fruit
>   good; or else make the tree corrupt, and his fruit corrupt: for the
>   tree is known by his fruit. (34)  **O generation of vipers, how can ye,
>   being evil, speak good things? for out of the abundance of the heart
>   the mouth speaketh.** (35)  A good man out of the good treasure of the
>   heart bringeth forth good things: and an evil man out of the evil
>   treasure bringeth forth evil things.

And for these things In the Day of Judgment, every idle word that men shall speak will be accounted for as by our words shall we be justified and by our words shall we be condemned.

> (36)  ***But I say unto you, That every idle word that men shall speak,
>   they shall give account thereof in the day of judgment. (37)  For by
>   thy words thou shalt be justified, and by thy words thou shalt be
>   condemned***.

If we sin willfully AFTER we have received the full knowledge (epignosis) of the Truth, there remains no more sacrifice for sins.  The sacrifice of Jesus will not atone for the continued willful sins after being warned to keep His sacrifice.

One may willfully speak evil towards the hearing of this full knowledge as the Scriptures are being opened up to their hearing ears but then will not be able to escape the final judgment of Gehenna (the fiery indignation which shall devour the adversaries).   There is a point of no return as one will then be cast into the lake of fire…the “second death”.

> Hebrews 10:26-30 KJV (26)  ***For if we sin wilfully after that we have
>   received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice
>   for sins,*** (27)  But a certain fearful looking for of **judgment and
>   fiery indignation, which shall devour the adversaries**.

This will be the final Judgment upon them and it will be  “without mercy”.

> (28)  *He that despised Moses' law died without mercy under two or
>   three witnesses: (29)  Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall
>   he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and
>   hath counted the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was sanctified,
>   an unholy thing, and hath done despite unto the Spirit of grace? (30) 
>   For we know him that hath said, Vengeance belongeth unto me, I will
>   recompense, saith the Lord. And again, The Lord shall judge his
>   people.*

It is a final condition of raging with the tongue and the judgment of every evil word that will come out of the mouth. The gnashing of teeth…the wrathful evil speaking against the Word of Truth and evil speaking against those who will speak it....  will bring weeping in one’s life and there will be no remedy until one dies from this earth.

We must hear Him and "give diligence" lest He drags us to the Judge (God) who will then deliver to the "officer" (meaning to habitually practice) who then cast us into prison until we have paid the last mite (death).  We are to take heed on how we hear lest we be judged by Him. The "officer" is the continually practicing of evil speaking of which we shall not depart from until we die from this earth.  There will be no more sacrifice for willful, continual evil speaking which will then bring us torment upon ourselves.

> Luke 12:57-59 KJV (57)  *Yea, and why even of yourselves judge ye not
>   what is right? (58)  When thou goest with thine adversary to the
>   magistrate, as thou art in the way, give diligence that thou mayest be
>   delivered from him; lest he hale thee to the judge, and the judge
>   deliver thee to the officer, and the officer cast thee into prison.
>   (59)  I tell thee, thou shalt not depart thence, till thou hast paid
>   the very last mite.*

Hades is also cast into the lake of fire as there will be no understanding ….the wicked shall not understand.

> Matthew 13:49-50 KJV (49)  *So shall it be at the end of the world: the
>   angels shall come forth, **and sever the wicked from among the just,
>   (50)  And shall cast them into the furnace of fire: there shall be
>   wailing and gnashing of teeth**.*

Their “worm” (inconsiderate, continual blurting of evil) shall not die neither shall their fire be quenched.  Their own tongues (unceasing evil speaking) shall bring themselves torment for every idle word shall be judged in the Day of Judgment…and this Judgment upon the wicked will be in this earth as “all flesh”  shall see it.

> Isaiah 66:24 KJV (24)  *And they shall go forth, and look upon the
>   carcases of the men that have transgressed against me: f**or their worm
>   shall not die, neither shall their fire be quenched;** and they shall be
>   an abhorring unto all flesh.*

Yet,  if we believe, Jesus has the keys of “hell” (Hades =  unseen) and of the death.

He comes to give us an understanding which severs the wicked from the just as some will not believe and others will believe in what He says.

Out of His mouth went a sharp two-edged sword… and His words will sever the wicked from the just.   His opening up of the Scriptures will separate the unbelievers from the believers.

> Revelation 1:16-18 KJV (16)  *And he had in his right hand seven stars:
>   **and out of his mouth went a sharp twoedged sword:** and his countenance
>   was as the sun shineth in his strength.*

When we “see” Him, we also must humble ourselves as John did as he fell at His feet as “dead”.  We must die to sin...dying to evil speaking...and humble ourselves.

> (17)  *A**nd when I saw him, I fell at his feet as dead.** And he laid his
>   right hand upon me, saying unto me, Fear not; I am the first and the
>   last:*

He that lives became dead and is living now for evermore.

We also are to continually die to sin (to “become dead” to the sin…keeping His daily sacrifice in our mortal bodies),then we shall also continue to live His eternal as He lives “for evermore”.

We must die to sin when we hear His voice as He opens up the Scriptures to our understanding which will sever the wicked from the just.

This is the key of the death…to keep His daily sacrifice (to become “dead” to sin) by always dying to sin so that we might live His eternal life and not die (“Behold, I am alive for evermore”).

> Revelation  (18)  ***I am he that liveth, and was dead; and, behold, I am
>   alive for evermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell and of death***.

The key to death:  If we are planted together in the likeness of His death, we shall also be in the likeness of His resurrection.   we must die to sin so that we live His eternal life in this earth.  We must put sin to death in our own lives....no longer serving the sin.

> Romans 6:5-6 KJV (5)  ***For if we have been planted together in the
>   likeness of his death, we shall be also in the likeness of his
>   resurrection:*** (6)  Knowing this, that our old man is crucified with
>   him, that the body of sin might be destroyed, that henceforth we
>   should not serve sin.

If we are dead unto the sin, we shall also live His eternal life in this earth.

> Romans 6:11 KJV (11)  **Likewise reckon ye also yourselves to be dead
>   indeed unto sin, but alive unto God through Jesus Christ our Lord.**

Jesus has the keys of Hades and of the death.   His knowledge is the key to getting out of “Hades”…the unseen or the not knowing…the lack of understanding.  There is currently no knowledge of God as all have turned away.

He comes to give us an understanding so that we might know Him who is true.   We then depart from the sin and Hades…the not knowing.   We then show we know the true God by that understanding that Jesus gives us .   This is the true God and eternal life.

> 1 John 5:20 KJV (20)  *A**nd we know that the Son of God is come, and
>   hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and
>   we are in him that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the
>   true God, and eternal life***.

Yet, many who are preaching the doctrines and commandments of men (their laws of man for us to keep) are actively taking away the key of knowledge so that we might have His knowledge.

Those who are preaching the commandments of man do not themselves enter in to understand the Scriptures (that make us wise unto salvation) nor those they are preventing from entering in. We are in the "graves" then.

> Luke 11:52 KJV (52)  **Woe unto you, lawyers! for ye have taken away the
>   key of knowledge: ye entered not in yourselves, and them that were
>   entering in ye hindered.**

His people are destroyed for lack of knowledge (the “Hades” = “unseen”…or the lack of knowledge) .  His knowledge is not being preached by those leaders who have rejected knowledge.  They are not preaching it to their congregations who are perishing because of a lack of knowledge. The shepherds are not feeding the flock...His people.

> Hosea 4:6 KJV (6)  ***My people are destroyed for lack of knowledge:
>   because thou hast rejected knowledge, I will also reject thee, that
>   thou shalt be no priest to me:*** seeing thou hast forgotten the law of
>   thy God, I will also forget thy children.

The “dead” in sins and trespasses have no knowledge.  But He comes to give us His knowledge and those who will hear His voice shall live.

> Ephesians 2:1-2 KJV (1)  ***And you hath he quickened, who were dead in
>   trespasses and sins;*** (2)  Wherein in time past ye walked according to
>   the course of this world, according to the prince of the power of the
>   air, the spirit that now worketh in the children of disobedience:

He has the keys of Hades (not knowing) and death.  The “dead” in sins and trespasses shall hear the voice of the Son of God who comes to give us an understanding and they that hear His word and believe on Him that sent Him shall live. They shall depart from the "graves"...places where no knowledge of God is being heard.

Those who will do good shall stand up to life while those who will do evil towards the hearing of His voice shall stand up to condemnation.

> John 5:24-29 KJV (24)  Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that heareth
>   my word, and believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and
>   shall not come into condemnation; but is passed from death unto life.
>   (25)  **Verily, verily, I say unto you, The hour is coming, and now is,
>   when the dead shall hear the voice of the Son of God: and they that
>   hear shall live.** (26)  For as the Father hath life in himself; so hath
>   he given to the Son to have life in himself; (27)  ***And hath given him
>   authority to execute judgment also, because he is the Son of man. (28)
>   Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which all that are
>   in the graves shall hear his voice, (29)  And shall come forth; they
>   that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and they that have
>   done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation.***

Again, The “dead” are the “dead in sins” as our mortal bodies are good as dead when we “live” in the sin...the judging of others...the evil speaking of others.

> Ephesians 2:4-6 KJV (4)  *But God, who is rich in mercy, for his great
>   love wherewith he loved us, (5)  **Even when we were dead in sins, hath
>   quickened us together with Christ,** (by grace ye are saved;) (6)  And
>   hath raised us up together, and made us sit together in heavenly
>   places in Christ Jesus:*